# Confusion about simplifying tensor product in a dielectric example

Tags: electromagnetism, tensor-calculus, dielectric

I am confused about converting the tensorial form of an equation to a compact form that does not include the indices.

I had this confusion while reading a [research paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1563285), where it says the following:

> Electrostriction is generally defined as quadratic coupling between strain and electrical field. The strain $S_{ij}$ and the electric flux density $D_m$ are expressed as independent variables of the electric field intensity $E_m$, $E_n$ and the stress $T_{ij}$ by the constitutive relation as:

$$S_{ij} = c_{ijkl} T_{kl} + M_{mnij} E_n E_m$$

$$ D_m = \varepsilon_{mn} E_n + 2 M_{mnij} E_n T_{ij}$$

where $c_{ijkl}$ is the elastic compliance, $M_{mnij}$ is known as the electric-field-related electrostriction coefficient, and $\varepsilon_{mn}$ is the linear dielectric permittivity. An isotropic electrostrictive polymer film contracts along the thickness direction and expands along the film direction when an electric field is applied across the thickness, assuming that the only nonzero stress is that applied along the length of the film.

The constitutive relation then is simplified as:

$$S = c T + M E^2$$

$$ D = \varepsilon E + 2 M E T$$

where

$E = E_3$ ,

$D = D_3$,

$S=S_1$,

$T=T_1$,

$c=c_{11}$,

$M= M_{31}$,

$\varepsilon = \varepsilon_{33}$

> Because our analysis is based on these simplified relations, we will
> no longer specify the orientation of parameters and field variables in the following.

My question is that if we didn't have the above simplifying conditions of the variables, can we still write $E \otimes E$ or $E_n E_m$ as $E^2$ ?

Comment: I think there's a problem with the ij subscripts in the 1st term on the RHS of the 1st eq.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it